# convert for loops to while loops comparing arrays

Tags: bash

On occasion (like 4 or 5 times in an 8hr shift) I have to check that the sites from being served from a shared server are loading.  I currently have a script that does this, however I am using nested for loops to iterate over two arrays to ensure I am only checking sites that are actually being served from the server in question.  I have been reading and discovered that there can be problems with this method, but can not figure out how to turn them into while loops or some other method.  I set two arrays one is all of the sites and the IPs that dig says is serving them, along with their status code from curl (203.0.113.231 - foobar.com - Status_code=200).  The other array is all of the IPs on the server. it then compares the first array to the second and only prints the elements from the first array that are in the second array.

```
#!/bin/bash
_ORGIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
_sitecrls=($( for _x in $(grep 'ServerName' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost_* |grep -v '000_defaults' |uniq |awk '{print $NF}'); do printf "%s %s %s %s %s\n" "$(dig +short $_x |head -n1) - $_x - Status_code=$(curl -so /dev/null -w %{http_code} $_x)" | sed '/^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/!d'; done ))
_ips=($(ip a |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//g' -e '/inet /!d' -e '/127.0.0.1/d' -e 's/inet //g' |cut -d'/' -f1))
echo
  for _x in "${_sitecrls[@]}"
  do
    for _z in "${_ips[@]}"
    do
      echo "$_x" |sed -n "/$_z/p"
    done
  done
echo
IFS=$_ORGIFS
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having, or are you trying to assuage a sense of vague unease? (I'm not being sarcastic, this is a real question)

Comment: No problems the script appears to work correctly.  I have just been reading and came across several instances where they say you should not do this like here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor  @glenn

Answer (score 1):

Setting `IFS` the way you do is a fine way to split command output into elements. Then, using `for` to  iterate over array elements is a perfect.

I don't quite grok your code, but I wonder this this is easier to maintain:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

ips=( $( ip a | sed -n '/\<inet\>/ { /127\.0\.0\.1/! s,.*inet \([^/]*\)/.*,\1,p }' ) )
hosts=( $( awk ' /ServerName/ && !/000_defaults/ && !seen[$NF]++ {print $NF} ' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost_* ) )

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do 
    domain=$( dig +short $host | head -n1 )
    status=$( curl -so /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' $host )

    found=false
    for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
        if [[ $domain == $ip ]]; then
            echo "$domain - $host - Status_code=$code"
            found=true
            break
        fi
    done

    if ! $found; then
        echo "no IP found for $domain - $host - Status_code=$code" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: your script produces undesired results

Comment: I'm not surprised: I clearly can't test it.

Comment: part 1 @glenn
When run on my server not one of my employers production servers, it does not print the status code.  and prints sites for which there was no ip.
    [REDACTED] - [REDACTED] - Status_code=
    [REDACTED] - [REDACTED] - Status_code=
    no IP found for  - fakesit1.com - Status_code=
    no IP found for  - fakesite2.com - Status_code=
    no IP found for  - fakesite3.com - Status_code=
    [REDACTED] - [REDACTED] - Status_code=

Comment: part 2 @glenn
I changed the fakesites to actual sites not served by this server
[REDACTED] - [REDACTED] - Status_code=
[REDACTED] - [REDACTED] - Status_code=
no IP found for 66.29.217.134 - www.colt.com - Status_code=
no IP found for 204.76.112.44 - www.conagrafoods.com - Status_code=
no IP found for 64.30.228.49 - www.cbs.com - Status_code=
[REDACTED] - [REDACTED] - Status_code=
the  only time it should print is when the site is being served from the server in question.  The current script performs this way as is.  If you say that setting IFS to newline is fine, I will stick with it.